# How to make notifications vibrate phone react native expo

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo, vibration

I need notifications to vibrate the phone repeatedly until the user performs an action like clicking on the notification. I have found no way to make this work yet. At first, I sought to solve it using the [Vibrate Api](https://reactnative.dev/docs/vibration) from react native expo. But I later came to realize that the expo cannot react to notifications if app is killed and user did not interact with the notification  [as stated here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/notifications/#listening-to-notification-events). The only other way is to give the notification a setting to vibrate and the interval. But I can't seem to find a way to do that. I am using node js to send the notification, which is practically the same code as [this](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node). This are the only [formats](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/) used to send a message. There is no vibrate. But on the [initial page](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/notifications/#notificationcontentinput), I see them adding vibrate. I must be mistaken somewhere or lost. I suppose this can be done somehow, else there wouldn't be alarm apps. How can I do this? On my android phone, the notification doesn't even vibrate at all and The app would be useless if I do not have this feature. Thank you ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later found the answer to this. On andriod, you must create a [channel](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/overview/) and include it when sending the notifications. All explanation in the docs. You would be able to create a vibration pattern and so forth. Also if your like me who did the sending of notification in the backend (I used nodejs), you can still create a channel but it has to be on the frontend. Use this code in a useEffect:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
  name: 'default',
  importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
  vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
  lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
});
```

}

You can replace 'default' with whatever name you want to call the notification channel. I haven't yet found out how to do this on ios. If I do, I will update. Hopefully I don't forget ):

Comment: did you find a way on IOS?

Comment: @genericatz I haven't yet developed for ios. But I am using eas build now. Standalone. 10X better and you still use expo. Nothing complicated. I am use notifee for notifications